# Hide some elements when text starts to overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm making a button that has text content and an icon, I'd like to make it so that when it starts to put content onto multiple lines it hides the icon.

Here's a code example with three cases: one where the content fits just fine and the icon looks good, one where the content can't fit and the icon is pretty lame, and a last one that's more like how I would like it to work with the icon being hidden.

```html
<style>
  .some-flex-box {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 300px;
  }
  
  .fun-icon {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
  }
  
  .reactive-button img {
    height: 16px;
  }
</style>

<div class="some-flex-box">
  <div>First box fits content</div>
  <button class="reactive-button">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/WPVG_icon_2016.svg/1024px-WPVG_icon_2016.svg.png" />
    awesome
  </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="some-flex-box">
  <div>Second box has lots of content and puts everything on multiple lines</div>
  <button class="reactive-button">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/WPVG_icon_2016.svg/1024px-WPVG_icon_2016.svg.png" />
    uh oh
  </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="some-flex-box">
  <div>If the second example hid the icon (like this) that would be super sweet</div>
  <button class="reactive-button">
    this works
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: In the second line the contents of the text are being used to compute the relative width of the containers since using flexbox.  You could have something where JS is used to "monitor" the size of the element and if the height grows you know the text has wrapped but is a hacky solution.  Really think best option is to set some container sizes to guarantee things won't wrap where don't want them to and/or use media queries to show/hide elements at various screen sizes where know the wrapping will kick in.

Comment: The question is *why* would you want to hide an icon in that particular case? Maybe we can provide you with some arguments why to live it ;)

Comment: In practice I'm trying to follow the [material design guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/buttons/guidelines) which specify that wrapping text is bad for buttons.

As a compromise of having icons in the button and it shrinking and wanting to wrap, I'm hoping to come up with a solution that avoids wrapping by hiding display elements first.

Comment: See?! Icon - or no icon, the button text should not wrap. I would never get rid of the icon, I'd rather get rid of the extra text. Anyways you can use `@media`.